# How do I enable antialiasing on QML Shapes?

Tags: qt, qml

Here's a QML file that has a Dial control and a custom shape side by side:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0


Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200

    RowLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        spacing: 5

        Dial {
            id: dial1
        }

        Control {
            id: dial2

            implicitWidth: dial1.width
            implicitHeight: dial1.height

            antialiasing: true

            Shape {
                anchors.fill: parent

                antialiasing: true

                ShapePath {
                    strokeWidth: 1
                    strokeColor: dial2.visualFocus ? dial2.palette.highlight : dial2.palette.dark

                    startX: dial2.width/2
                    startY: 0

                    PathArc {
                        x: dial2.width/2
                        y: dial2.height
                        radiusX: dial2.width/2
                        radiusY: dial2.height/2
                        direction: PathArc.Clockwise
                    }

                    PathArc {
                        x: dial2.width/2
                        y: 0
                        radiusX: dial2.width/2
                        radiusY: dial2.height/2
                        direction: PathArc.Clockwise
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since `antialiasing: true` is set on both the Control and the Shape, I would have expected the path to look smooth. However, it looks jagged:

[image: Dial and custom shape]

How can I antialias the shape?

Answer (score 28):

According to [the blog post about QtQuick Shapes](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/let-there-be-shapes/), you need to either enable multisampling on the whole scene or on a QtQuick layer.

You appear to be using a QQmlApplicationEngine, in which case you can simply set the default surface format in main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(8);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to restrict this setting to a single QtQuick layer, you can also set the number of samples like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        id: root
        anchors.fill: parent
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.samples: 4
        // your shapes here ...
    }
}
```

Setting it on a layer appears to be broken for me with `vendorExtensionsEnabled: true` on the Shape, which is the default. Setting it to `false` appears to work.

Comment: This was great input! Before, I had set the surface format on the window directly, after creating the engine.
`QSurfaceFormat format; format.setSamples( 8 ); auto window = dynamic_cast<QQuickWindow*>( engine.rootObjects().first() ); window->setFormat( format );`
However, after moving to Qt 5.12, this approach doesn't work anymore, it apparently needs to be set before the engine is instantiated.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working with Qt 5.15 and neither of the approaches have any effect on my Shapes :-( I also tried disabling vendor extensions as suggested, but no luck. Still jagged.

Comment: @LubosD, it does work. Just a few minutes ago I've used it to improve graphics quality. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709212/how-to-improve-graphics-quality)

Comment: @EmonHaque But you're not using any Shape/ShapePath/PathPolyline components, are you? I'm trying even the most trivial cases and still no antialiasing is taking place.

Comment: @LubosD, all those icons (A, B,C, J, K and L) you see are `string` put inside `Shape{ShapePath{PathSvg{path: string}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling smooth?  I would check but i am currently using Qt 4.8 for a project and do not have 5.x loaded to try it for myself.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-item.html#smooth-prop