# How to do Antialiasing on Custom QQuickItem with QSGGeometry

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I created my own Custom QQuickItem which should draw a curve using QSGGeometry:

```
curve = new QSGGeometryNode;
curve->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial,true);
curve->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry,true);
curve->setGeometry(_geometry);

_geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(),_xdata.size());
QSGGeometry::Point2D *points = _geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();
for(int i=0;i<_xdata.size();i++) {
    points[i].x = _xdata[i];
    points[i].y = _ydata[i];
}
_geometry->setLineWidth(2);
_geometry->setDrawingMode(GL_LINE_STRIP);
curve->setGeometry(_geometry);
```

How can I enable Anti-Aliasing for this curve?

Comment: This might answer your question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895449/how-do-i-enable-antialiasing-on-qml-shapes/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
QQuickView view;
QSurfaceFormat format = view.format();
format.setSamples(16);
view.setFormat(format);
view->setSource("...");
view.show();
```

Comment: How would you do this if you don't use a QQuickView but the ApplicationWindow in qml? Then you only have the  QQmlApplicationEngine on the c++ side.

Comment: Ok, for the ApplicationWindow you can do it like this
QQuickWindow* window = (QQuickWindow*) engine.rootObjects().first();
 QSurfaceFormat format;
 format.setSamples(8);
window->setFormat(format);

However, is there a way to do it only for the QSGNode, and not for the whole window?