# Border changes width depending on rectangle width

Tags: qt, qml

I have a rounded rectangle in QML code and I noticed strange behavior of rectangle's border, when I resize the rectangle its border appears to be flickering a little and if I look closely I can see that its border seems to be changing its width from 1 to 2 and back or something like that, while in code it definitely set to 1 and doesn't depend on anything else. Also rectangle corners seem to be a little bit wider than border at straight sections. I tried to take screenshots of such rectangles but on the screenshots rectangles looks alright so I suppose it may be some rendering issue? It definitely noticeable in the app. On screenshots you can see that the second rectangle has its borders a little bit blurry, thats when the border appears to be wider than normal.

Is this a known problem and are there any settings in Qt I need to change to get consistent border width on my elements?

I'm using Qt 5.15, QML, C++. I could reproduce this behavior on Windows 10 on two different 1440p monitors.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:

Since my main project is pretty big I will provide example project where I was able to reproduce the issue:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        width: parent.width / 3
        height: parent.height / 3

        color: "#F8F8F8"
        radius: 8

        border
        {
            color: "red"
            width: 1
        }
    
        Text
        {
            id: valueField
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            font.pointSize: 10
            text: "100"
            color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is reproducable when width and height of rectangle are bound to width and height of window, if I set them to one specific value - no such issue is present.

Comment: What does your `QPainter::renderHints` return? Try setting `QPainter::Antialiasing` if it's not set. But in any case, the graphics engine has to make some sort of compromise if the rectangle width or height is a fractional number of pixels.

Comment: @TonyK Although the OP does not show any code, they do mention using QML, so it's unlikely that QPainter is being used.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576756/7427152

Comment: or this: ` QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);`?

Comment: @JarMan @Amfasis
I've updated the question with example code, none of the solutions helped. But I did find that if I do `height: Math.round(parent.height / 3)` instead of simple `height: parent.height / 3`, then the issue is gone. If this is the correct solution then I can post an answer for the issue.

Comment: @monkeber I believe you are correct that this is the solution - QML accepts floats for size but seems to render only in integers, which can causes rounding issues where borders show as either 0 or 2 pixels instead of 1. Rounding as you did has fixed this issue for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I do `height: Math.round(parent.height / 3)` instead of simple `height: parent.height / 3`, then the issue is gone. As per the comment from @DFaller :

> I believe you are correct that this is the solution - QML accepts floats for size but seems to render only in integers, which can causes rounding issues where borders show as either 0 or 2 pixels instead of 1. Rounding as you did has fixed this issue for me in the past.

So posting this as the answer for now.