# qml rectangle with customized rounded borders

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, rounded-corners

So there was need of qml rectangle with customized rounded corners. I ended up crating one with shapes, pathLines, pathArcs and bit of math.

Somehow my arcs/rounded corners are not sharp/fine as Rectangle with radius property.
How cam I make those corners more fine ?

```
Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: root
        width: 300
        height: 300
        property string color: 'red'
        property int rightTopCornerRadius: 10
        property int rightBottomCornerRadius: 20
        property int leftBottomCornerRadius: 30
        property int leftTopCornerRadius: 40

        Shape {

             ShapePath {

                strokeWidth: 5
                strokeColor: root.color
                startX: root.leftTopCornerRadius > 0 ? root.leftTopCornerRadius : 0
                startY: 0
                fillColor: "transparent"
                capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap
                 fillRule:ShapePath.WindingFill

                PathLine { y: 0; x:root.width - root.rightTopCornerRadius}
                PathArc {
                    x: root.width; y: root.rightTopCornerRadius
                    radiusX: root.rightTopCornerRadius; radiusY: root.rightTopCornerRadius

                }

                PathLine { x:root.width; y:root.height - root.rightBottomCornerRadius}
                PathArc {
                    x:root.width - root.rightBottomCornerRadius; y: root.height
                    radiusX: root.rightBottomCornerRadius; radiusY: root.rightBottomCornerRadius
                }

                PathLine { x:root.leftBottomCornerRadius; y:root.height}
                PathArc {
                    x:0; y: root.height - root.leftBottomCornerRadius
                    radiusX: root.leftBottomCornerRadius; radiusY: root.leftBottomCornerRadius
                }

                PathLine { x:0; y:root.leftTopCornerRadius}
                PathArc {
                    x:root.leftTopCornerRadius; y: 0
                    radiusX: root.leftTopCornerRadius; radiusY: root.leftTopCornerRadius
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Above Code Output]

where else Normal rectangle with rounded corners with very fine borders.

```
Rectangle {
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       width: 300
       height: 300
       radius: 30
       border.width: 5
    }
```

[image: Rounded Rectangle]

I tried playing with some of the share properties, but nothing helped.
like joinstyle, capstyle, fillrule

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895449/how-do-i-enable-antialiasing-on-qml-shapes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, there are several options to do that. First of all you have to turn the QtQuick multisampling on. Add the following lines into your main.cpp:

```cpp
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QSurfaceFormat format;                       //
format.setSamples(8);                        //  add these lines, change the value if needed
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);    // 

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
```

Then you can play with [Item.antialiasing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#antialiasing-prop) and [Item.smooth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#smooth-prop) properties of your `Shape`.

Besides that, I would recommend to write a custom item using QQuickItem deriving, taking the `Rectangle` [sources](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickrectangle.cpp.html#_ZN15QQuickRectangle15updatePaintNodeEP7QSGNodePN10QQuickItem19UpdatePaintNodeDataE) as example.

Here are 2 images: your `Shapes` with 8 samples, `antialiasing: true`,
`smooth: true`,  and a common `Rectangle` with default settings:

[image: test]

Comment: Thank you , for the solution and suggesting a more standard approach to have control over Rectangle.